# Display rows returned by query

Tags: yii2

I am a total beginner in yii2. I have an `actionView` in my controller to which I pass the `$id`. I have written a query which returns the join from 3 tables. I want to know how can I display specific columns from these rows in my view named `view`.  This is my `actionView`...

```
public function actionView($id)
{

    $select = [
        'user.username',
        'package_subscriptions.package_id',
        'order.order_number',
    ];
    $query = new Query;
    $query->select($select)
            ->from('order')
            ->innerJoin(['user'],'order.user_id = user.id')
            ->innerJoin(['package_subscriptions'],'order.user_id = package_subscriptions.user_id')
            ->all();

    return $this->render('view', [
        // What should I write here
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import Query class

```
use yii\db\Query;
```

Code in your actionView

```
public function actionView($id)
{

    $select = [
        'user.username as username',
        'package_subscriptions.package_id as package_id',
        'order.order_number as order_number',
    ];
    $query = new Query;
    $query->select($select)
            ->from('order')
            ->innerJoin(['user'],'order.user_id = user.id')
            ->innerJoin(['package_subscriptions'],'order.user_id = package_subscriptions.user_id');

    $command = $query->createCommand();
    $list  = $command->queryAll();

    return $this->render('view', [
        'data'=>$list, // pass data to view
    ]);
}
```

**Query** return an **array** ,you can use in **view** as below :

```
foreach($data as $val)
{
  echo $val['username'];
  echo $val['package_id'];
  echo $val['order_number'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public function actionView($id)
{

    $select = [
        'user.username',
        'package_subscriptions.package_id',
        'order.order_number',
    ];
    $query = new Query;
  $results=  $query->select($select)
            ->from('order')
            ->innerJoin(['user'],'order.user_id = user.id')
            ->innerJoin(['package_subscriptions'],'order.user_id = package_subscriptions.user_id')
            ->all();

    return $this->render('view', [
       'results'=>$results
    ]);
}
```

in your `view.php`

```
<?
foreach($results as $result){
?>
username:<?=$result['username']?>
<br>
Package id:<?=$result['package_id']?>
<br>
order number:<?=$result['order_number']?>
<?
}
?>
```